# Use Linq to flatten a nested list instead of a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a recurring class - I've simplified it below.

```
public class SiloNode
{
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public string Url { get; private set; }
    public List<SiloNode> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

Although, in theory, it could nest forever, the nodes will only ever go down two levels. So, a top-level node can have a child, but a child can't have a child.

I have a master list containing all of the top level nodes with their nested child nodes.

However, I need to get all nodes into a single flat list - node 1, followed by its children, followed by node 2 etc.

My knowledge in this area is limited, but I could do something like a `foreach` over the master list and create a new list, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SiloNode> GetLinks(IEnumerable<SiloNode> masterList)
{
    var newList = new List<SiloNode>();

    foreach (var node in masterList)
    {
        newList.Add(node);
        newList.AddRange(node.Children);
    }

    return newList;
}
```

However, I know there's probably a much better way available but I just can't work out how to convert the `foreach` into a `Linq` statement that will do the same thing. In other words, select the parent and its children together.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think maybe you want to look into the `.SelectMany` linq helper to flatten lists of lists.

Comment: I understand how I can get a list of all children with a  .SelectMany but not how to retrieve the parent and the children nodes together.

Comment: "probably a much better way available" - sure you could do this with a handful of `Select`s, `Concat`s, whatever - but would it be *better*? Not sure.

Comment: All great answers guys - guess it's down to faster finger first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`, just concat the single parent and it's children:

```
List<SiloNode> newList = masterList.SelectMany(n => new[]{ n }.Concat(n.Children)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to preserve the order and flatten more than one level of children I think something like this will work just fine. `var nodes = GetLinks(masterList);` or use it in a loop `for(var node in GetLinks(masterList))`

```
public IEnumerable<SiloNode> GetLinks(IEnumerable<SiloNode> masterList)
{
    foreach(var node in masterList) 
    {
        yield return node;
        foreach(var children in GetLinks(node.Children))
            yield return children;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`masterList` contains already the parent node, and concat the child nodes

```
var nodes = masterList.Concat(masterList.SelectMany(x=> x.Children));
```

Comment: Works also. But note that the result is different. This will first list all parents and then the children whereas OPs loop(and the other LINQ versions) will start with the parent but directly concat each parent's children.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the remarque

Answer (score 2):

If there are only going to be two levels, something like that should do:

```
public IEnumerable<SiloNode> GetLinks(IEnumerable<SiloNode> masterList)
{
    return masterList.SelectMany(m => new SiloNode[] { m }.Concat(m.Children));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this answered before, but couldnt find the question. This does what you want without recursing really deep in the node structure:

```
public IEnumerable<SiloNode> Flatten(IEnumerable<SiloNode> nodes)
{
    var queue = new Queue<SiloNode>();

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(node);
    }         

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var node = queue.Dequeue();

        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
             queue.Enqueue(child);
        }

        yield return node;
    }
}
```

EDIT: this doesn't preserve the ordering you want, but you can use a stack instead of queue.